# Check if two editors edit the same news

Tags: php

How I can check corretly if user edit news in admin and other user want edit and save this news. How I can prevent this?

Now I have test:

on page edit I have input hidden with:

```
<input type="hidden" value="$item->updated_at">
```

updated_at - this is a column with date when last time user update news.

In controller on save I have:

```
 if($item->updated_at != $this->request->get('updated_at'))
                exit('please enter on other time here');
```

But this not working, when user reload page, because when I reload page `input` update with new time from database.

Comment: You could remove the 'update' feature? Otherwise I don't understand what you really need.

Comment: Store the current DB content in a hidden input, or session. On the next page load, prior to update see if the DB content has changed. If it has changed tell the user they must reload the form because changes have been made.

Comment: I don't know how I can do this.